# Mongodb java 3.0 driver misunderstanding

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using the java 3.0 Mongodb driver, and trying to use distinct.

With the deprecated DBCollection I can do the following:

```
collection.distinct("tokens.account_id", new BasicDBObject("_id",new ObjectId(objectiId)))
```

However, I can't seem to accomplish the same thing using the newer MongoCollection.

Answer (score 0):

As per the new driver of MongoDB the API is bit changed
Now we have to do

```
collection.distinct("tokens.account_id",String.class).filter(new BasicDBObject("_id",new ObjectId(objectiId)))
```

Let me know if it works for you.